Tring to find this font for a while! I tried some font identification sites, but fail
If you find it, you are great! Also here's the refrence pic:

Its from Mezmeriser mv.
Regards,

._. Pink


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Try likefont.com for automated CJK fornt recognition.
